# Can I change an Azure application type from "Web app / API" to "Native"?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have configured an Azure application as type "Web app / API", but would like to switch it to "Native". According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/04/11/changing-an-existing-native-application-to-a-web-appapi-to-get-existing-keys/, the reverse seems possible. It says that I should edit the manifest's 'publicClient' field, which is, "the field that determines whether an application is a web app/api or native application. When it is true, it is a native application otherwise it is a web app." However, both editing the app manifest on the web UI and uploading a newly edited copy of the manifest will return the message, "Failed to update application xxx. Error details: GenericError".

[image]
Is there a way to do this at all, or should I start from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link you provided, there are 2 important notes

- The goal of the steps provided in the article is changing Native app to Web App, which does not necessarily mean it will work the other way around.
- This is a work around and is not recommended

> Note : This is not recommended practice, and this is solely meant for
>   customers who have keys on their native application but can't get to
>   them anymore; so they need a workaround to get access to the native
>   application Keys

So, my recommendation is to start from scratch because even if it worked, it will not be supported

However, below are the main differences between native app manifest and web app manifest. Check if this works for you.

**Key/Value pairs in Native App Manifest**

```
"availableToOtherTenants": true
"homepage": null,
"identifierUris": [],
"oauth2Permissions": [],
"publicClient": true,
```

Comment: Thanks. No change. Error continues. I suppose I may have to start from scratch. I've tried all available workarounds and solutions so far. It seems I cannot convert the app from a "Web app / API" type to "Native".

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue, before you set the `publicClient` to `true`, you need to set the `"identifierUris": [xxxxxx]` to `"identifierUris": []` in the Manifest
, then it will work fine.

Comment: I did as you said, but still get the same error when I return to try to set publicClient to true.